# Accessing application variables from a Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I have a variable that I need globally available throughout my app (so I've set @account in the applicationController).

However, a plugin that I have needs access to the same variable.

Note:  This variable is distinct on each request.

What is the best way of creating this architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
class Account
  def self.current
    @current
    # or: Thread.current[:current_account]
  end
  def self.current=(a)
    @current = a
    # or: Thread.current[:current_account] = a # ..if you want to be thread-safe.
  end
  ...
end

# your controller's before_filter:
def assign_account
  ...
  Account.current = @account # But remember to set nil if none found!
end

# Any code in your app (view, model, almost anything):
<%= Account.current.name if Account.current %>
```

Comment: Would this work so that each thread is independant?  I don't want to cross the streams between users...

Comment: For now, Rails usually are single threaded. Instead of using an instance variable `@current`, you may use `Thread.current[:current_account]` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Setting @account in your app controller doesn't make it globally available throughout the app - models can't access it for example.  Any instance var set in the controller will be available only in the controller or views.  If the plugins have controller and view code then this code should be able to access the variable in the normal way, as long as the variable is set before the plugin controller code runs for example.

If you provide more details about what you want to do (ie where/how you want to access @account) then someone may be able to suggest a good approach.

Comment: @account is set in a before_filter on every request.
The plugin adds a default scope to some AR queries